# Using VS2012 GUI to bind ListBox to List<T>

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I feel like this is such a basic question, but I've spent 2 days trying to get it working with no success.  Thank you for your time.

#### Problem Definition

- Visual Studio Express 2012 - Visual C# Windows Form Project
- Classes and Members

  - MyForm (`Form`)

    - myListBox - `ListBox`
  - MyDataElement

    - firstName - `string`
    - lastName - `string`
  - MyDataManager

    - myDataList - `List<MyDataElement>`

Using the GUI, how can I bind `myListBox` to `myDataList`?  More specifically, how do I go about instantiating `MyDataManager` so that `myListBox` gets populated with the list's values?

#### Steps Already Taken

I can create DataSources without trouble, but I cannot get the ListBox to show the contents of the underlying list.  I have tried:

- Binding the ListBox to a standalone `MyDataManager` object
- Creating a member in `MyForm` of type `MyDataManager` and binding the ListBox to that member

I couldn't get either to work.  I've also tried changing the DisplayMember property to no avail.

Incidentally, I can get it to work properly by manually setting the DataSource (e.g., `myListBox.DataSource = myDM.myDataList`) in the main method of `MyForm`, but for future reference and my own edification I would love to learn how to do this through the GUI (if it's even possible).

#### Sample Code

```
public class MyDataElement
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}

public class MyDataManager
{
    public List<MyDataElement> myDataList { get; set; }
    
    // Constructor.
    public MyDataManager()
    {
        myDataList = new List<MyDataElement>();

        // Populate list for testing purposes.
        myDataList.Add(new MyDataElement { firstName = "John", lastName = "Smith" });
        myDataList.Add(new MyDataElement { firstName = "Jane", lastName = "Doe" });
    }
}
```

In the main method of `MyForm`:

```
// ...
myDM = new myDataManager();
InitializeComponents();
// ...
```

I have also tried reversing this order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your View's DataContext with MyDataManager using Resources(In your case MyDataManager is considered as the ViewModel), see these [anwsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590446/how-do-i-set-a-viewmodel-on-a-window-in-xaml-using-datacontext-property). The VS GUI will be able to find your MyDataManager class members then. Hope it helps