# DataContext is not bind in the XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to WPF + MVVM architecture. In my application, I am trying to implement "DataContext" in the XAML itself as below

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPF.UI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyWPF.UI.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:Northwind_DataViewModel></vm:Northwind_DataViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

I am getting "The name 'Northwind_DataViewModel' does not exists in the namespace 'clr-namespace:MyWPF.UI.ViewModel".

I have ViewModel file. Before using "DataContext", I built this application.

Could you please let me know what is wrong with my code?

thanks

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590446/how-do-i-set-a-viewmodel-on-a-window-in-xaml-using-datacontext-property?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

> The name 'Northwind_DataViewModel' does not exists in the namespace 'clr-namespace:MyWPF.UI.ViewModel".

Chances are, you compiler is right. There is no class named `MyWPF.UI.ViewModel.Northwind_DataViewModel` in your project. Make sure it exists, has a public, parameterless constructor, is not an inner class of something and not generic. If that's the case, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In case ***namespace is declared in separate assembly*** from where your XAML resides, you have to ***provide assembly name as well***.

Sample:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Similarly, provide your assembly name where this namespace resides *(Assuming assembly name is MyWPF.UI)*:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyWPF.UI.ViewModel;assembly=MyWPF.UI"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot your responses. Finally I got the solution. Actually, this project was placed in a shared folder. So, I moved it to my local drive (C:). Now, it is working fine without any issues.

I guess, in shared path / shared folder, it may not work. Please let me know if I am wrong.

thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem, you need to understand how the `DataContext` works. This answer contains a lot of hints and links to supporting tutorials:

[ReSharper WPF error: "Cannot resolve symbol "MyVariable" due to unknown DataContext"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549826/resharper-wpf-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-myvariable-due-to-unknown-datacont/25549827#25549827)