# Is it possible to access and set class variables from XAML in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

In part of a XAML code maximum and minimum values are set as follows:

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <wf:NumericUpDown  Maximum="12000" Minimum="120" x:Name="MyNumericUpDown" TextAlign="Right"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

And in the same C# program inside a class I have the following:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int max { get; } = 12000;
        public int min { get; } = 120;

        ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to set the Maximum and Minimum values of NumericUpDown by using the class properties instead of hardcoding them? So that of I change class property values the XAML values autonomically updated.

Comment: Yup, and it's called [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0)

Comment: What you describe is "one way" databinding

Comment: How and where do you instantiate your `MyClass`? The values are hardcoded in both your examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it's possible, and even what I'd consider to be fundamental in WPF development. It's called [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0#create-a-binding). I'll be implementing a simple one way data binding here which binds to a property on the code behind file (i.e `MainView.xaml` binds to `MainView.xaml.cs`), but you can bind to any class you'd like, this then forms the fundamentals of [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern).

Xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainView"
    Title="MainView"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <!-- Snip -->
</Window>
```

The important part is `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`. Right here we're telling the window to bind to itself (i.e the code behind file). This is required for anything to work. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4590558/9363973) Q&A to see how to bind to something else.

Continuing on:

```xml
<wf:NumericUpDown Maximum="{Binding Max}" Minimum="{Binding Min}" />
```

Here we're telling the `NumericUpDown` component to get its `Maximum` and `Minimum` values from the data context. Now, one caveat, you can *only* bind to *properties* and nothing else. So, if you ever run into a problem where your bindings aren't working, check to see if you're binding to a property or not. Here's the code of code behind file

```cs
public class MainWindow
{
    public int Max { get; } = 12000;

    public int Min { get; } = 120;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

---

This is a *one* way data binding, i.e the XAML can only read these values. For things like an input box, you'll need to use [TwoWay bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0#direction-of-the-data-flow). And if anything changes those values (currently impossible, but may be in the future), then you need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

---

**P.S**: No guarantees for the code. I just typed it out in this text box without any auto complete and the last time I did WPF is quite a while ago. Just leave a comment if something doesn't work and I'll try my best to fix it

Comment: Be aware that OP already has a "view model" class. Using the Window instance as DataContext makes no sense. There should instead be `DataContext = myClass`, with myClass being an instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: @Clemens we have no idea where `Min` and `Max` are declared, because `MyNamespace` and `MyClass` are obviously placeholders, they might as well be declared on the code behind for all we know. And if they're not, I linked to a StackOverflow Q&A which explains how to set a class as data context which is not the code behind file.

Comment: "*In the same C# program inside a class I have the following*" - they are obviously declared in MyClass, as shown in the question. If an actual class name is *potentially* different, OP could well handle that.