# Thread callback when its window is closed

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a `MainWindow` class that launches "baloon" process. It opens a new window within a baloon start to move.

In my MainWindow class, I want to have the number of baloon launched process in real-time, that's why, when I manually close a Baloon Window, I want the MainWindow class to be warned.

Here's what I already wrote :

```
private void LaunchBaloonProces(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (countBaloonProcess() < 5) {
            Application app = System.Windows.Application.Current;
            ClassLibrary1.Ballon b = new Ballon();
            Thread unThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(b.Go));
            unThread.Start();
            if (allPaused) unThread.Suspend();
            unThread.Name = "Ballon";
            processList.AddLast(unThread);               

            refreshInformations(); // <= Here's the method Thread child should call
        } 
        else {
            informations.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "Can't create more than 5 baloons");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create multiple UI threads there.  Don't do that.  You're asking for a world of hurt.  Just use a single UI thread to manage your entire UI.  Only offload non-UI tasks to other threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a delegate and pass that to your child instance when you create it.

E.g.:

```
class ChildWindow{
    public ChildWindow(MainWindow.RefreshInformationsDelegate callback){
        //Do work

        //Notify MainWindow that we are closing
        callback();
    }
}

class MainWindow{
    public static delegate void RefreshInformationsDelegate();

    private void LaunchBaloonProces(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (countBaloonProcess() < 5) {
            Application app = System.Windows.Application.Current;
            ClassLibrary1.Ballon b = new Ballon(new RefreshInformationsDelegate(refreshInformations));
            Thread unThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(b.Go));
            unThread.Start();
            if (allPaused) unThread.Suspend();
            unThread.Name = "Ballon";
            processList.AddLast(unThread);
        } 
        else {
            informations.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "Can't create more than 5 baloons");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I pass an instance of `RefreshInformationsDelegate` to the `Ballon` constructor. If you want this to happen on window close instead of thread finish then store the callback as an instance variable and call it with `callback()`in the `Form_Closing` event.

Comment: Thanks, once I've stored the callback as an instance variable (`callbackClosing = refreshInformations()` I suppose), where is the `Form_closing` event ? In the Child ?

Comment: Try creating a method called as follows `void OnWindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e){callbackClosing();}` and then adding `Closing += OnWindowClosing;` to your constructor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683450/handling-the-window-closing-event-with-wpf-mvvm-light-toolkit/7225853#7225853 seems to think this will work, I'm not that familiar with WPF

Comment: Servy is right in his comment on your question though. I am simply answering **how** to do it, not suggesting you should :)