# How to check if Window is already open? Duplicate Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a button that opens a Window.

If the button is pressed again, it opens a duplicate of the same window.

```
info = new Info();
info.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
info.Show();
```

How do you check if the Window is already open, and deny a duplicate from being opened again?

I can't use `info.ShowDialog()` because it disables the `Main Window`.

---

**Solutions that have not worked:**

```
Info info = new Info();

if (!info.IsActive)
{
    info = new Info();
    info.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
    info.Show();
}
```

---

```
Info info = new Info();

if (info.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
{
    info.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
    info.Show();
}
```

---

```
public static bool IsWindowOpen<T>(string name = "") where T : Window
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
           ? Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any()
           : Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any(w => w.Name.Equals(name));
}

private void buttonInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    if (!IsWindowOpen<Window>("Info"))
    {
        Info info = new Info();
        info.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
        info.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are keep creating new instance of `Info` and based your check on the new instance. You should declare you `Info` window in your class level, and check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.IsLoaded` field or bind the `.ContentRendered` event

### Edit 1 -

Window1:

```
public class Window1 : Window
{
    private Info info = null;
    private Boolean IsInfoOpened = false;

    protected void OpenInfo()
    {
        if (this.IsInfoOpened) return;
        this.info = new Info();
        this.info.ContentRendered += delegate { this.IsInfoOpened = true; };
        this.info.Closed += delegate { this.IsInfoOpened = false; }
        this.info.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried if (!info.IsLoaded) in many different ways, though button still makes a duplicate window.

Comment: This works perfect. I made the Info and Boolean at the top of the class and put the if statement in the button.

Answer (score 2):

The sensible approach is to just keep track of the Window instance so you don't have to find it back later.  Add a field:

```
    private Info infoWindow;
```

If it is null then you know that the window doesn't exist yet, so you'll want to create it.  Use the Closed event to set the variable back to null.  If it is not null then you want to make sure that the window gets restored.  So:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (infoWindow == null) {
            infoWindow = new Info();
            infoWindow.Closed += (s, ea) => infoWindow = null;
            infoWindow.Owner = this;   // optional
            infoWindow.Show();
        }
        else {
            if (infoWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized) {
                infoWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
            infoWindow.Activate();
        }
    }
```

And you probably also want to close the window automatically when the window that contains the button is closed:

```
    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (infoWindow != null) infoWindow.Close();
    }
```

Comment: This works really well. Though the Info window loses focus if the Main window button is clicked again, which is the proper function, but @zaylau answer kept the focus on the Info window, which I want to use in this case.

Comment: If you want to keep the focus on the info window then you must use ShowDialog().  Well, you already dismissed that.  I guess what you really mean is that you want to keep it above the main window, set the Owner property.

Comment: Actually you are right, I had put the Owner property on the other solution and that's what was keeping the focus. Your answer works identical.

Answer (score 2):

Create a form only when value is not null. 
If the form was closed put the value back to null with the FormClosed event.

```
public static Info info;

if(info == null){
  info = new Info();
  info.Show();
}
```

put an event form close on the info form

```
 private void info_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
 {
    MainForm1.info = null;
 }
```

It works for me

Comment: Is this for WinForms? I'm actually using WPF, but I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Yes it is for windows forms but if you search for form closing event for WPF this should work as well. maybe try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683450/handling-the-window-closing-event-with-wpf-mvvm-light-toolkit